# COUNT on joined rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to make an SQL call where i count the rows on the joined call for each row

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id_feed.id) as price_count, prices.id as id FROM prices
LEFT JOIN id_feed ON id_feed.id_prices = prices.id
WHERE prices.id_user = :id_user
```

prices table:

```
id name  id_user
1  name1 21
2  name2 21
3  name3 4
```

id_feed table:

```
id id_prices price
1  1         30
2  1         30
3  1         30
4  2         30
5  2         30
6  3         30
```

Result

```
id id_prices price_count
1  name1     3
2  name2     2
```

Comment: Please show the results you want.

Comment: You probably want `GROUP BY prices.id`

Comment: I updatet the result with the requested result :)

Comment: Should probably learn how to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Group by doesnt sum Up the number og results from the joined table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a join and aggregation:

```
select p.id, p.name, count(*) price_count
from prices p inner join id_feed i
on i.id_prices = p.id
where p.id_user = :id_user
group by p.id, p.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3d43fd69a88cf6af531615642d12b6e6).
Results for `id_user = 21`:

```
> id | name  | price_count
> -: | :---- | ----------:
>  1 | name1 |           3
>  2 | name2 |           2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing window functions.  Something like this:

```
SELECT p.*, f.*, COUNT(f.id) OVER () as price_count
FROM prices p LEFT JOIN
     id_feed f
     ON f.id_prices = p.id
WHERE p.id_user = :id_user
```

Comment: I cant seem to make that work, i just get: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '()

Comment: This works starting in MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.2.0 -- which was released in May 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to want window function :

```
SELECT prices.*, prices.id as id ,
      count(*) over (partition by id_prices) as price_count
FROM prices LEFT JOIN 
     id_feed 
     ON id_feed.id_prices = prices.id
WHERE prices.id_user = :id_user
```

Comment: I cant seem to make that work, i just get: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY id_prices)